# Compile MUPDF 1.7a for android

Tags: android, mupdf

I'm trying to compile mupdf 1.7a source to get mupdflib.so for android platform.
I followed the steps in documentation but I got this error:

> mupdf/pdf/name-table.h : No such file or directory

Could anyone help me how to get this file ?

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

RTFM?? Item 10 in the ReadMe.txt explains:

=====================================================================

Finally, you will need a copy of a 'generated' directory. This is not
currently available to download.

The normal mupdf build process involves running some code on the host
(the machine on which you are compiling), rather than the target (the
machine/device on which you eventually want to run mupdf). This code
repacks various bits of information (fonts, CMAPs etc) into a more
compact and usable form.

Unfortunately, the android SDK does not provide a compiler for the host
machine, so we cannot run this step automatically as part of the android
build. You will need to generate it by running a different build, such
as the windows or linux native builds.

We do not make a snapshot of the generated directory available to
download as the contents of this directory change frequently, and we'd
have to keep multiple versions on the website. We assume that anyone
capable of building for android is capable of doing a normal hosted
build.

On windows (where you are using cygwin), or on linux/macos, this can be
as simple as running 'make generate' in the top level directory.'

=====================================================================

So in the "top" directory of the mupdf tree, "make generate" will get you all those in-build generated files.

Comment: this readme is not valid for mac os "ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignore"